# Can I configure auto-sorting rules in Outlook 2007/2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I want to set up an Outlook rule that automatically sorts mail into an appropriate folder based on the contents of the subject line:

So I get emails with case numbers (CSSxxxxxx) in the subject line.  I want to configure a rule that sends all such mails to a folder called the same value (So mails with CSS123456 in the subject are automatically put in folder CSS123456).

I know I can do this case-by-case but I have quite a *lot* of cases to deal with; so what I want to do is to simply create the folder for each case and have the rule be automatically configured from that point on.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what I need. I see companies use salesforce to sort out case numbers messages.

Looks like people have written outlook macros for this very function.

http://joelslowik.blogspot.com/2011/04/sort-emails-in-outlook-using-macro-and.html